# Crawling Twitter Data using Tweepy

Tags: python

Can somebody help me? I have an error code while crawling twitter data with Tweepy. Here the codes:

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#natuna",count=10, lang="id", since="2020-01-10").items(): 
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [4], in <cell line: 1>() -> 1 for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#natuna",count=10, 2 lang="id", 3 since="2020-01-10").items(): 4 print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)

AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'search'
```

Answer (score 2):

`api.search` doesn’t exist (as stated in the output)

Instead you have to use `api.search_tweets`

```py
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search_tweets,q="#natuna",count=10, lang="id", since="2020-01-10").items():
    print (tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
```

https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.search_tweets

Comment: but, the next error: <tweepy.cursor.ItemIterator at 0x2b1cda85930> how to fix it?

Comment: Is that the full error output?

Comment: yes, after I run that codes

Comment: I updated the code, check now